# Opensearch - Parsing Date

Tags: kibana, datetime-format, opensearch

I am trying to interpret a specific date format from NYC Open Data in Opensearch and get it to port over to Kibana.

The date in NYC Open Data is formatted as "2020 Sep 24 07:00:40 PM". Opensearch can read this, however, it is not a date that is supported by Kibana.
I tried the following code on the date field (which is in a dictionary):

"incident_datetime": {"type": "date", "format": ["YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"]}

How can I convert the "2020 Sep 24 07:00:40 PM" into a proper date field ("2020/09/24 07:00:40") for kibana?

Answer (score 0):

you can create an ingest pipeline ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html)) to convert the "2020 Sep 24 07:00:40 PM" timestamp to the "2020/09/24 07:00:40" format using a `date` processor ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/date-processor.html)). E.g.,

```
{
   "date": {
        "field": "incident_datetime",
        "formats": ["yyyy MMM dd hh:mm:ss a"],
        "timezone": "America/New_York",
        "target_field": "timestamp",
        "output_format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
   }
}
```

this processor will store the converted date into a new field (`timestamp`)

Alternatively to the Elasticsearch ingest pipelines, you can resort to other ETL tools such as Logstash, that also provides the same feature